# Create multiple-page/html using Svelte

Tags: svelte

It seems every tutorial or example I found only designed for SPA (Single Page Application), what should be done to generate multiple page/html? (without having to create a project for each page)

reason why I need multiple page:

1. backend was built using another language (I'm not using Sapper) so what I need is just static html and javascript.
2. some of my friends suffer from really slow reload on development (they have too many components)

**EDIT:** Finally made a template to generate multiple-SPA based on `vite-plugin-mpa`, [svelte-mpa](https://github.com/kokizzu/svelte-mpa) you can degit/clone and modify to suit your needs

Comment: I am interested in the same thing.  I imagine you just need to configure webpack/rollup to do this for you, but as someone currently learning, I am not fully sure how to do that.  Has anyone done this?

Comment: I am also looking for the same.

Comment: I created a Svelte-Template which is configurable for multiple svelte-pages https://github.com/Tom-Siegel/multi-page-svelte

Comment: alternate solution https://github.com/PierBover/svelte-ssr-example

Comment: http://github.com/IndexXuan/vite-plugin-mpa/tree/main/examples/svelte-mpa-app but need a bit modification: http://github.com/vitejs/vite/commit/c69f83615292953d40f07b1178d1ed1d72abe695

Comment: UPDATED: https://github.com/kokizzu/svelte-mpa